# How to customize the visibility of buttons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer

The built-in toolbar named "Composer" has an icon "Duplicate Composer".

I wish to toggle the visibility of this button in the toolbar.

How do I achieve this using pyqgis?

Comment: I don't think you can hide individual icons but you can hide groups of icons which includes the **Duplicate Composer** icon and all the other icons by right-clicking on the toolbar and deselecting the bottom set of options (_Composer_, _Paper Navigation_ etc). You can also access these options via _View_ > _Toolbars_. Hope this helps!

Comment: Right, but I'd like to have the same customization functionality for COMPOSER as already exists for MAIN QGIS toolbars: http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#figure-customization

Comment: ...you can (de)activate the toolbar icons of QGIS one by one there. But it can not be done the same way for COMPOSER toolbar icons.

Comment: I would be happy in case there exists workaround using QGIS API calls but so far I did not find anything useful for that.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it is a common request to show/hide individual composer icons. Which is probably why there's little or no information available regarding this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You probably moved on ages ago, but for anyone else with this problem, I found a hack'ish way to disable the Save button in all open composer windows:

```
for c in iface.activeComposers():
    if c.isVisible():
        w = c.composerWindow() # the QMainWindow of the print composer
        t = w.childAt(20,30) # its composer QToolBar
        t.setMovable(False) # to ensure nobody moves the toolbar which will mess with our logic
        b = t.childAt(18,12) # that toolbar's first QToolButton
        a = b.defaultAction() # that button's QAction
        a.setEnabled(False) # disable it ;-)
```

the QWidget's childAt method does the magic to return a reference to the objects we're interested in, so you could disable your "Duplicate Composer" button by increasing the first argument(x) of `b = t.childAt(18,12)` until it works. In fact, this could theoretically be used to find and manipulate any object in the print composer window. The x/y coordinates are relative to the top left corner of the window.

Since the QGIS GUI is programmed to use standard size icons (24x24 pixels) and menu sizes no matter what resolution your screen is, this should be fairly reliable, but the further away from the origin you go the more you risk future QGIS button additions ruining your carefully crafted code.

I hope one day the QGIS devs will expose all composer widgets in the API just like they've done for the main QGIS interface, then we could do this properly...

Comment: on second thoughts, Qt pixels aren't quite the same as my screen's pixels, at least not according to jRuler, no clue why. So it's probably safer to start with getting the left top corner of the first toolbar with something like t=w.childAt(0,w.menuBar().height()), then scanning right with t.childAt() in a loop at y coordinate t.height()//2 until you find the button you're interested in